# Build a new Javascript Object with fewer properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have an object with many props, and I am only interested in props 1,2,3

```
const { prop1, prop2, prop3, ...rest } = MyObj; //destructure, I know this much.
```

How do I build a new obj with only those 3 properties using spread, or destructure, or whatever;

the Long way

```
const myNewObj = {
    prop1: prop1,
    prop2: prop2,
    prop3: prop3
}
```

The fancy ES6 way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a tiny bit smaller that your long way:

```js
const { prop1, prop2, prop3, ...rest } = MyObj;

const myNewObj = { prop1, prop2, prop3 };
```

[image]

Comment: are you sure ? const myNewObj = { prop1, prop2, prop3 }; makes all props UNDEFINED ?

Comment: I added the image example to my response

Comment: @Paul-LouisMas, Please do not upload images of code. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You don't actually need the `...rest` here.

Comment: @joedotnot see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015

Comment: Ok. sorry I just tried it out now in REPL and it works ! The reason I asked is because I did something similar in React, and they all came out as undefined I don't know why.